# Отключение кеша Chrome для разработки веб-сайта

Tags: google-chrome, кэширование, браузер

Я изменяю внешний вид сайта (`модификации CSS`), но не вижу результата в Chrome из-за раздражающего постоянного кэша. Почти всегда да же не помогает `CTRL + F5`.

> Пробивал еще `Inspect Element` открыл `DevTools`, там во вкладке
>   `Network` на панели инструментов есть `Disable cache`. Поставил
>   галочку, но это работает когда открыт `DevTools`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот сам вопрос, есть какой то метод что бы отключить кэш браузера `Chrome` всегда но для определенного домена?

Comment: Заголовки с домена не пробовали отправлять запрещающие кешировать содержимое?

Comment: @Visman Это не вариант. Поскольку сайт очень большой, и в нем время от времени всегда меняется что то. И после того как разработку делается в локале, скидывается все на сервер, Ну и там все на всякий случай проверяется. А на сервере нельзя это сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Открываете devTools, затем правой на кнопку «обновления/перезагрузки страницы», очистить кэш и перезагрузить. Или не открывая devTools: `Ctrl+Shift+R`.

P.S: также можете использовать расширение [`NoCache`](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/no-cache/ogbfmfambmmhfdpfokohebghmcdbodbh), в котором можно настроить фильтрацию по URL.

Comment: Вы прочитали вопрос до конца? Там написано про `devTools`.

Comment: @StackOverflow, я перечислил все возможные варианты "очистки" кэша.